# commutativity taking the complement and taking fibers

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal M \rightarrow S$ be a projective irreducible scheme over the spectrum of a DVR and $U\subset \mathcal M$ an open subscheme surjective on $S$. Is it true for both points (generic and closed) of $S$ $$(\mathcal M\backslash U)_s = \mathcal M_s \backslash U_s\ ?$$